# Show that $\int_0^{\infty} P(n|\mu)d\mu =1$ where $P(n|\mu)$ is the Poisson probability distribution

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, poisson-distribution

I need to show that the Poisson probability distribution, given by $P(n|\mu)=\frac{\mu^{n}e^{-\mu}}{n!}$, is a well-behaved probability, i.e. $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}P(n|\mu)=1$ and $\int_0^{\infty} P(n|\mu)d\mu =1$.

I have done the first part by comparing it to the expansion of $e^\mu$, but am unsure how to do the second part. When I take the integral I end up with terms of $\infty^n$ and I don't know what to do with those.

Comment: The latter part amounts to showing $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ which can be done using integration by parts. The terms involving $\mu^k e^{-\mu}$ vanish as $\mu \to \infty$ which can be shown formally by L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @Ian will all of the terms not involve $\mu^{k}e^{-\mu}$ ?

Comment: They do, at least if you count $k=0$ (but that case doesn't need L'Hospital's rule).

Comment: For the second part you're integrating over $\mu$ from $0$ to $\infty$, and $\mu$ is Gamma$(n+1,1)$, so it integrates to $1$.